# Unknown column 'userc.u_id' in 'on clause'

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am using Codeigniter and I am trying to retrieve all users with role ID 3 with all their saved custom fields. For some reason, I get a database error with

"**Unknown column 'userc.u_id' in 'on clause'**"

```
   $this->db->join('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(data) AS custom_data, id AS dataid, u_id
     FROM ea_user_cfields userc
     GROUP BY id) AS tt', 'userc.u_id = ea.id','left');
    $this->db->join('(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS custom_name, id AS customid
     FROM ea_customfields AS cf
     GROUP BY id) AS te', 'userc.c_id = cf.id','left');
    $this->db->where('id_roles', $customers_role_id);



    return $this->db->get('ea_users ea')->result_array();
```

Actual query:

```
SELECT * FROM (`ea_users` ea) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(data) AS custom_data, id AS dataid, u_id FROM
ea_user_cfields userc GROUP BY id) AS tt ON `userc`.`u_id` =
`ea`.`id` 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS
custom_name, id AS customid FROM ea_customfields AS cf GROUP BY id) AS
te ON `userc`.`c_id` = `cf`.`id` WHERE `id_roles` = '3'
```

Comment: Table userc contains `userid` field or `u_id` ?

Comment: u_id, I removed the "as userid"

Comment: whenever this type of error come that means table not contain this column .

Comment: Then how can you got an error like " Unknown column 'userc.userid' in 'on clause". Please check with your database field and model file field name

Comment: You should put the column name instead alias.

Comment: I removed the "as userid", it now displays Unknown column 'userc.u_id' in 'on clause'' > essentially the same error

Comment: I forgot to change that in the title and post

Comment: try joining on `ea_user_cfields.u_id`

Comment: @SjoerddeWit that results in "Unknown column 'ea_user_cfields.u_id' in 'on clause'"

Comment: There is no table `userc` in your query. The usage of the table `ea_user_cfields` aliased as `userc` in the inner query doesn't count because of the `GROUP BY`. The query that contains `GROUP BY` **does not return rows** from table `ea_user_cfields`, it **generates new rows** using the data retrieved from table `ea_user_cfields`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the below code may be it helps you.

```
SELECT * FROM (`ea_users` ea) 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(data) AS custom_data, id AS dataid, u_id FROM
ea_user_cfields userc GROUP BY id) AS tt ON tt.`u_id` =
`ea`.`id` 

LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(name) AS
custom_name, id AS customid FROM ea_customfields AS cf GROUP BY id) AS
te ON tt.`c_id` = `cf`.`id` WHERE `id_roles` = '3'
```

Comment: instead of 'userc' > 'tt' and 'u_id' is added to the first left join select query

Comment: *LazyCoder_13* - you know you need to indent your code, which "I" did "for you". A simple CTRL-K would have done it here when posting answers.